# Does a 12V cable of an ATX power supply have an overcurrent protection on its own when more current is drawn than the cable could withstand?

Tags: power-supply, current, wire

I want to use an old ATX power supply to power a project of mine. For that I'd like to utilize a single 12V cable from the 20 pin connector which is 18 awg and therefore can safely handle around 6 amps. The Question is that if a load draws more amps than the cable tolerates but the 12V rail could supply, would there be any protection for the cable or do I need to use a fuse which trips before the current gets to high and therefore protect the cable in that manner?

Comment: It is better to gang wires as the OCP is central not on each plug, unless it’s a >=1kW for example then they may have separate protection You can verify with an Ohmeter

Comment: If you open the power supply you will probably find all the 12V wires (probably yellow) are on the same buss. Simply connect a wire of the appropriate size to that and also another for the ground.